# How to add points at intervals

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to add points to this graph at every 100 interval like shown in the graph. I have used this line in the gnuplot, but I get the error that "every" is an unrecognized token. I am using gnuplot v5. How can I add a point at interval of 100 in this graph?

```
set xtics 100
set yrange [ 0 : 3000 ] noreverse nowriteback
plot [x=100:1000] x every 100
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`every` can be used only for data files, not for functions. The simplest solution would be to set the number of samples:

```
set xrange [100:1000]
set samples 10
plot x with points
```